# Why is it that adding android.permission.CAMERA to the AndroidManifest.xml does not allow access /dev/video0 in C++?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-camera, android-permissions

The Android NDK r10c includes the headers for Video4Linux2 (V4L2), but even with android.permission.CAMERA, calls in C++ to access /dev/video0 are denied.  I've looked at both android-webcam [1] and simplewebcam [2].  It seems the the change in Kitkat from SELinux "permissive" to "enforcing" might be the culprit, but why then does NDK have APIs for most other sensors [3] but not the camera in C++.  This seems to leave a major gap for high performance augmented reality engines.  At least that's seems to be one of the cases for the NDK is for high performance game engines [4], but what the differences between a high performance game engine and a high performance augmented reality engine; access to the camera.  Is there another security setting to enable access to /dev/video0 on Kitkat 4.4+ in C++?

[1] - https://github.com/openxc/android-webcam 
[2] - https://bitbucket.org/droidperception/simplewebcam/overview 
[3] - mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ 
[4] - developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I did a little bit more digging around and found the camera gid is still defined in [Android 5.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.0.0_r7/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h) , but is no longer associated with the [android.permission.CAMERA](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.0_r7/data/etc/platform.xml)  when previously [it was](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r3.1/data/etc/platform.xml).

Comment: I found another [interesting source](http://www.zhauniarovich.com/files/asani/asani.pdf#page=24) which provided some clarification.  So it seems, as I previously mentioned, that to run with the camera gid the android.permission.CAMERA was sufficient in Jelly Bean but is no longer.  Then I guess question is, what permission is required to have my application run in the camera group?

Comment: I take it that access to the camera through mediaserver is insufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Is that possible in C++?

Comment: C++ certainly, NDK probably.  I assumed, based on your direct access to a /dev entry, that portability is not your biggest concern.  The screenrecord command accesses video encoders, surfaceflinger composition, GLES, and the media indexer from non-NDK C++.  (though not specifically the camera.)  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-release/cmds/screenrecord/  If your goal is to minimize latency, though, the language of choice may be less relevant than the IPC.

Comment: Portability is not that much of a concern.   The main goal is to reuse the existing high performance augmented reality engine and avoid some long wrapper from java to c++ to acquire images at full frame-rate into the C++ pipeline.  It seems everything is there in the NDK but the permission to access the camera device.

Comment: You can check `dmesg` output (or `cat /proc/kmsg`) for SELinux complaints.  Use `setenforce 0` to disable SELinux enforcing mode.  That'll tell you if SELinux changes have caused the issue.  (Requires root.)

Comment: It looks like I might have been looking at this in an old Linux-centric way.  It seems [OpenMAX AL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/omxal/specs/OpenMAX_AL_1_1_Specification.pdf#page=2) provides a camera abstraction layer which would avoid the need to use v4l2 and this is supported in the [NDK](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#openmax-al)

Comment: OpenMAX AL also provides a [camera example](https://www.khronos.org/registry/omxal/specs/OpenMAX_AL_1_1_Specification.pdf#page=497).

Comment: I was sadly mistaken.  While the OpenMAX AL headers include a camera interface definition, it is [not implemented](http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/openmaxal/index.html).

Comment: SElinux does not seem to be the problem.  The issue seems to be that the process is not executed with the camera gid.  If /dev/video0 is chmod'ed to 666 it is accessible, as per [simplewebcam](https://bitbucket.org/droidperception/simplewebcam)

Comment: If you chgrp /dev/video0 to the group of the package, it work as well.  Which leads me back to my first question, how does a package run in the camera group?

Comment: It seems [this change](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b8dd91a6b23c5098740fa080eb265e516e546dd9%5E%21/#F0) set is the real culprit.